# SimpleDateFormat "Unparseable date" Exception

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I am trying to parse datetime string with `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` but I keep receiving Unparseable date exceptions.

Here is the date format I am trying to parse: `2011-10-06T12:00:00-08:00`

Here is the code I am using:

```
try {
    String dateStr = "2011-10-06T12:00:00-08:00";
    SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    Date date = dateParser.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));         
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Which returns this error: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-10-06T12:00:00-08:00"`

As far as I know this is the correct way to use the SimpleDateFormat class but I'm not fluent in Java so I could be mistaken.  Any one know what my issue is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The timezone should be GMT-08:00 or -0800 (as Madcore Tom said). See [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone).

In Java 7 you can use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"

Comment: For the rest, non java7, you can try to use the 'javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(date)' and more info can be found here on this blog http://ta.cnci.org/java-blogs/236-convert-date

Comment: not working to me: Error convert date: Unknown pattern character 'X' fromdate: 1999-12-31T17:00:00+00:00

Answer (score 15):

I believe that SimpleDateFormat will not parse timezones with a colon in them (-08:00). It should be able to parse the date `2011-10-06T12:00:00-0800`.

Some simple string manipulation should help you get rid of the colon.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to format the value in `"2011-10-06T12: 00: 00-08: 00"`.

```
Example: SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH: mm: ssZ");
```

After, create the formating for formataction desired. 
Ex: `SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm: ss");`

and after make parse for date. 
Ex: `Date date = dateParser.parse (dateFormat);`
and print of date formated.

Below, one complete example.

```
String dataStr = "2011-10-06T12: 00: 00-08: 00";
SimpleDateFormat dataParser = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm: ss", Locale.US);
Date date;
Try {
date = dataParser.parse (dataStr);
System.out.println (dateFormatter.format (date));

} cath (ParseException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-10-06T12:00:00-08:00" ) 
    .format( 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US )  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and such.
    )
```

> Oct 6, 2011

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

You input string is in a format that complies with the [ISO 8106](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime` because your input strings includes an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-10-06T12:00:00-08:00" ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2011-10-06T12:00-08:00

Generate a string in your desired format. Let java.time automatically localize rather than hard-code formatting patterns.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US );  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and such.
String output = odt.format( f );
```

> output: Oct 6, 2011

When seralizing a date-time value as text, use the standard ISO 8601 formats rather than a localized format.

```
String output = odt.toLocalDate().toString() ;
```

> 2011-10-06

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
```

Comment: Ahh cool, I was testing it on Java 6 on Android, I'm surprised the Android implementation is more generous with what it parses, interesting to learn...

Answer (score 0):

For a date format like `2013-06-28T00:00:00+00:00`, this code should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure most of you got frustrated from the fact that SimpleDateFormat can not handle ISO8601 format.  Here is my little trick to solve this nuisance.

Create a list of Know format you know that you will use for your application and apply SimpleDateFormat to the list.  Now, in your formatDate() method, simple try all your known format and trap the Exception, then if still did not have a date, just use

```
Date d = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2013-06-28T00:00:00+00:00").getTime();
if (d == null)
try {
    SimpleDateFormater ...
}
```

to try it and see if that work.  For more info [Simple trick to convert Date format with timezone in Java!](http://ta.cnci.org/java-blogs/236-convert-date)

Answer (score -1):

I'd strongly recommend using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this sort of thing.

You're trying to parse an ISO Date format, and Joda does that 'out of the box', and will give you plenty of other benefits too.

I long ago gave up trying to get the standard JDK data classes to do helpful things.

Comment: would I mind posting some examples of how to use JODA time to solve this problem of parsing?

Comment: Those "many" benefits being? Among other things, It will also introduce exceptions trying to parse dates when daylight savings occur.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).