# java : Unparseable date Exception

Tags: java

I have this value,

> 2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00

which needs to be converted and set it in this format

> yyyyMMdd

I tried this way

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ParsedDate {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
                Locale.US);
        String s1 = "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00";
        Date d = sdf.parse(s1);
        String s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")).format(d);
        System.out.println(s2);

    }
}
```

But it is giving me

**Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00"**

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681782/simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception) - took me about 30 seconds of clicking those links on the right to find an exact match to your pattern.

Comment: +1 for having a concise compiling example

Comment: @BrianRoach, quite certainly is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this

```
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                    Locale.US);
            String s1 = "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00";
            Date d;
            try
            {
                d = sdf.parse(s1);
                String s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")).format(d);
                System.out.println(s2);
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Notice that I have removed **Z**

Comment: Thank you very much Sandeep Nair .

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00" )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE
)
```

> 20111119

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Parse your input as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
String input = "2011-11-19T00:00:00.000-03:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Extract the date-only value care about, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

The `DateTimeFormatter` class offers a predefined object with your desired format, [`BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE). This particular format is known officially as the “basic” variant of a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, where 'basic' means minimizing the use of delimiters.

```
String output = ld.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

> 20111119

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).