# Java - SimpleDateFormatter Unparseable Date

Tags: java, json, date

Using Java's SimpleDateFormat and Google's Gson library, I'm trying to parse the date from a Json file downloaded from the Minecraft library directory. There appears to be an issue when parsing the date using the following SimpleDateFormat: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

I've also tried the following:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssx
```

Since the file is actually downloaded from the web, I have no means of changing it. So the solution must lie within altering my code to either not include the date, or removing the problematic code from my source. This happens to be quite a problem, since my application dies when the date is parsed, and appears to be a parsing issue, rather than a problem with the file.

The date formats are as follows:

```
2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500
2013-10-25T15:00:00+02:00
```

Both of the above dates crash it. And both of them come from separate files. I've browsed the web for multiple solutions and none of them seem to fix it.

I've even asked on the `#technic` channel and browsed the `TechnicLauncher` source code, and found pretty much nothing to help. And since the class I'm using is actually the exact same as the Technic Launcher, it's perplexing me. If you'd like to peruse the source code, you can take a look here: [GitHub :: LauncherCore](https://github.com/TechnicPack/LauncherCore/blob/master/src/main/java/net/technicpack/launchercore/util/DateTypeAdapter.java)

Comment: Your first format and date work for me.

Comment: You might find these answers helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681782

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 - use the format code X

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
    String date1 = "2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500";
    String date2 = "2013-10-25T15:00:00+08:00";

    try {
      System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(date1));      
      System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(date2));
    } catch (Exception e ) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }     
  }
}
```

produces the output

```
Wed Dec 18 05:41:38 GMT 2013
Fri Oct 25 08:00:00 BST 2013
```

When run in Ireland in winter.

Comment: `2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500` is not the same as `Wed Dec 18 00:41:38 GMT 2013` because the timezone is GMT. Wouldn't it be `Wed Dec 18 05:41:38 GMT 2013`. Removing the 'Z' just ignores the timezone, and assumes the JVM's default timezone

Comment: This only helped me find whether the format was operating correctly, It didn't actually assist with my problem.

Comment: You stated that your problem was that it crashed when you used the 'Z' suffix. The solution I proposed was to use the 'X' suffix instead which a) does not crash and b) gives the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Java date/time is a major piece of headaches.  Anyway, the trick is that I used, and seem to work, both xml calendar parser combine with SimpleDateFormat.  I also posted this a while back on my [blog: a simple trick for date format](http://ta.cnci.org/java-blogs/236-convert-date) and may be something there you can use too.  But anyway, here is the answer.  Simply take this method and make a few small tweet and plug in (replace) the deserializeToDate() method on that DateTypeAdapter class:

```
   private Date deserializeToDate(/*JsonElement*/String json) /*Json*/ParseException {
      Date d = null;
      String date = json; // json.getAsString();
      try {
         d = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(date).getTime();
      } catch (Exception e) {} // ignore
      if (d == null) {
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = 
                  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
         d = dateFormat.parse(date);      
      }
      return d;
   }

   @Test
   public void shouldParseXmlDateTime() {
      String date1 = "2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500";
      String date2 = "2013-10-25T15:00:00+08:00";

      try {
        System.out.println(deserializeToDate(date1));      
      } catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }     
      try {
         System.out.println(parse(date2));      
       } catch (Exception e ) {
         System.out.println(e);
       }     
   }
```

and this should produce:

```
Wed Dec 18 00:41:38 EST 2013
Fri Oct 25 03:00:00 EDT 2013
```

Comment: Aspirin for that headache: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [java.time](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: As much as this is useful to others, this doesn't solve my problem. The issue I'm having is that the date that I retreive from my file causes a JsonParseException when run.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, you want me to fix the LauncherCore ... Anyway, you can do it too... All you have to do is: download the LauncherCore, make some change and repackage it.  The change change you need to make is in the DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate()?  Simply replace with the method I changed above.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what it is that I'm supposed to fix.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that this doesn't actually change anything. I get the exact same result: `Exception: JsonSyntaxException, Message: 2013-10-25T15:00:00+02:00`

Comment: can you share with me what you done with the DateTypeAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Until bug is fixed:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" )
)
```

When bug is fixed:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500" )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2013-10-25T15:00:00+02:00" ) ;
```

That *should* also work for `2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500`. Unfortunately, it does not. The `OffsetDateTime` class has a **bug that bites when the offset-from-UTC portion lacks the optional colon** between hours and minutes. So `2013-12-18T00:41:38-05:00` would work, but not `2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500`.

As a workaround, define a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2013-12-18T00:41:38-0500" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2013-12-18T00:41:38-05:00

For more discussion, see similar Questions:

- [*SimpleDateFormat “Unparseable date” Exception*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7681782/642706)
- [*Cannot parse String in ISO 8601 format, lacking colon in offset, to Java 8 Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43360852/642706)
- [*Java 8 Date and Time: parse ISO 8601 string without colon in offset*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46487403/642706)

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This section left intact as history.

FYI, if you used [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/Calendar classes, you could simply pass that [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string straight into a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor without the bother of a formatter. Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 as its defaults.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z", timeZone );
```

If you want to work in UTC without adjusting to a time zone, just omit the timeZone stuff from code above.

If you need a java.util.Date object for other purposes, convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).