# How to convert String variable to date

Tags: java, date

```
SimpleDateFormat sm=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String dateString="22/11/1982";
    Date date;
    try{
        date=sm.parse(dateString);
        cm.setChargeDate(date); 
        System.out.println(date);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code above gives error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "22/11/1982"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.rss.master.bean.ChargeExeMappingBean.save(ChargeExeMappingBean.java:452)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat "Unparseable date" Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681782/simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. The problem of "Unparseable date" has been covered [many many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+date+unparseable) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dateFormat is wrong.
It must be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sm=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: thank you..i got output  Tue Oct 11 00:00:00 EST 1983  need date value only how i can remove  00:00:00 EST time value

Comment: @Rajats.kutti if is not realy clear what the result should be. Please improve your question.